# Call to undefined function - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use a helper functions but I got this error in my view :

```
Call to undefined function createSubCategories()
```

path of my helper functions:

```
Http\Controllers\Utilities\Helpers.php
```

my hlper :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Utilities;


    function createSubCategories($parent_cat_id = 0)
    {

        $subs = DB::table('categories')->where('parent_cat_id', '=', $parent_cat_id)->get();
        if (count($subs) > 0) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($subs as $sub) {
                echo '<li>' . $sub->title_fa;
                echo $this->createSubCategories(($sub->id));
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
```

in composer.json :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":
    [
        "app/Http/Controllers/Utilities/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

I used `composer dump-autoload`.

my view:

```
{{createSubCategories(0)}}
```

Answer (score 4):

**solved:**

I just removed the namespace :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Utilities;
```

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your problem and the solution is to leave out the line

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Utilities;
```

in your Helpers.php

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem that you have mentioned above. in my composer.json, I did not integrate the helper functions. By integrating in composer.json->autoload->files, now it is ok.

```
 "autoload": {
 "files":[
 "app/Helper/setting.php"
  ]
  }
```

if your path is alright then it will be ok. For Every change of your helper function you must run the command `composer dump-autoload`.